# Table is not perfect

Tags: tables, two-column, size, textwidth, fit

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Methodology}
\documentclass[a4paper, 8pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|} 
\cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Variable}}                    & \textbf{Definition}                                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ 
\hline
\textbf{Dependent Variables}                              &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     \\ 
\hline
Stunting                                                  & {[}(weight/height) standard deviation]*100; Z-score below -2                                                                                                                                                                        \\ 
\hline
ARI                                                       & had cough last 2 weeks/short or rapid breath/discomfortable chest                                                                                                                                                                   \\ 
\hline
\textbf{Independent Variables}                            &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     \\ 
\hline
Cooking location                                          & 0= if outdoor and 1= if indoor                                                                                                                                                                                                      \\ 
\hline
Fuel type                                                 & 0= non-smoke producing/clean fuel(lpg, natural gas, biogas, coal, and charcoal) , 1=smoke producing/solid fuel(kerosene, wood, straw, shrubs, grass, animal dung)                                                                   \\ 
\hline
Smoke exposure risk (SER)                                 & high SER (if smoke-producing cooking fuels = 1 and indoor cooking = 1), moderate SER (if smoke-producing cooking fuels = 1 and outdoor cooking = 0), and low SER (if non-smoke-producing cooking fuels = 0 and indoor cooking = 1)  \\ 
\hline
Child's age (in Months)                                   & 0= if "0-12", 1= if "13-24", 3=if "25-36", 4= if "37-48", 5= if "48-below 60"                                                                                                                                                       \\ 
\hline
Male Child                                                & 1= if yes, 0=if no                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\hline
Child's Birth Order                                       &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     \\ 
\hline
Child Size during birth                                   & 0=if very large, 1=larger than average, 2=average, 3=smaller than average, 5=very small                                                                                                                                             \\ 
\hline
Wealth index                                              & ( 0= if poorest, 1= if poorer, 2=if middle, 3= if richer, 4=if richest                                                                                                                                                              \\ 
\hline
Mother's age at the time of her first delivery (in years) & 0= if "below 21", 1= if "21-30", 3=if "31-40", 4= if "41-48"                                                                                                                                                                        \\ 
\hline
Mother's education                                        & 0= "no education", 1="primary dropout", 2="primary completed, 3="secondary dropout", 4="secondary", 5="higher"                                                                                                                      \\ 
\hline
Mother's smoking status                                   & 1= if yes, 0=if no                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\hline
Antenatal Care                                            & 1=if WHO recommended 8 or more visits, 0= if less than 8 visits                                                                                                                                                                     \\ 
\hline
Region (Division)                                         & 7 divisions; Barisal=1, Chittagong=2, Dhaka=3, Khulna=4, Rajshahi=5, Rangpur=6 and Sylhet=7                                                                                                                                         \\ 
\hline
Living Urban                                              & 1=if yes, 0=if no                                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. "Minimal" in this case could be that  a table with 2-3 rows is more than enough to find  the issue.

Comment: Does your use of `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}` indicate that you use the `beamer` document class? Please confirm.

Comment: `8pt` is *not* a valid option of the `article` document class and is simply ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it that your main issue is that the table's columns are too wide and hence that the table won't fit within the bounds of the textblock.

If this hunch is correct, I suggest you switch from a `tabular` to a `tabularx` environment, set its overall width to `\textwidth`, and allow automatic line breaking in both columns. Furthermore, as the second column contains a lot more material than the first, the second column should be wider than the first.

I would also do away with all vertical lines and most horizontal lines. To help readers distinguish divisions between cells, the following code also provides for automatic hanging indentation.

The following solution employs the `article` document class. It may not be optimal for other document classes, say, the `beamer` class.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{%
  >{\RaggedRight\hsize=#1\hsize\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}X}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L{0.6} L{1.4} @{}} % 0.6+1.4=2
\toprule
Variable & Definition \\ 
\midrule
Dependent Variables &  \\ 
\cmidrule(r){1-1}
Stunting & [(weight/height) standard deviation]${}\times100$; Z-score below $-2$ \\ 

ARI & had cough last 2 weeks\slash short or rapid breath\slash discomfortable chest  \\ 
\addlinespace
Independent Variables &  \\ 
\cmidrule(r){1-1}
Cooking location & 0 if outdoor, 1 if indoor  \\ 

Fuel type & 0 = non-smoke producing\slash clean fuel(lpg, natural gas, biogas, coal, and charcoal), 1 = smoke producing\slash solid fuel (kerosene, wood, straw, shrubs, grass, animal dung) \\ 

Smoke exposure risk (SER) & high SER (if smoke-producing cooking fuels = 1 and indoor cooking = 1); moderate SER (if smoke-producing cooking fuels = 1 and outdoor cooking = 0); and low SER (if non-smoke-producing cooking fuels = 0 and indoor cooking = 1)  \\ 

Child's age (in months) & 0 if ``0--12'', 1 if ``13--24'', 3 if ``25--36'', 4 if ``37--48'', 5 if ``48--below 60''   \\ 

Male Child & 1 if yes, 0 if no \\ 

Child's Birth Order &  (really nothing?)\\ 

Child Size during birth & 0 if very large, 1 if larger than average, 2 if average, 3 if smaller than average, 5 if very small \\ 

Wealth index & 0 if poorest, 1 if poorer, 2 if middle, 3 if richer, 4 if richest \\ 

Mother's age at the time of her first delivery, in years & 0 if ``below 21'', 1 if ``21--30'', 3= if ``31--40'', 4= if ``41--48'' \\ 

Mother's education & 0 if ``no education'', 1 if ``primary dropout'', 2 if ``primary completed, 3 if ``secondary dropout'', 4 if ``secondary'', 5 if ``higher''  \\ 

Mother's smoking status & 1 if yes, 0 if no \\ 

Antenatal Care & 1 if WHO recommended 8 or more visits, 0 if less than 8 visits  \\ 

Region (Division) & Seven divisions: Barisal=1, Chittagong=2, Dhaka=3, Khulna=4, Rajshahi=5, Rangpur=6 and Sylhet=7 \\ 

Living Urban & 1 if yes, 0 if no  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```